# vue js скрыть Input при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как можно скрыть `input` при клике на кнопку? Скрыть, не используя стили (навроде `document.getElem....id('test').style.display = "none"` (или visible ='hidden'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
  <input v-if="inputVisibility" type="text">
  <button @click="hideInput">Hide input</button>
</div>

data() {
  return {
    inputVisibility: true
  }
},
methods: {
  hideInput() {
    this.inputVisibility = false;
    // или можно тоггл
    // this.inputVisibility = !this.inputVisibility;
  }
}
```

Еще есть директива `v-show`. Отличие в том, что `v-if` не рендерит, если условие `false`, a `v-show` рендерит, но в css пишет `display: none`.
Подробнее тут https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html